# Basic scraper that collects the description from gallery website

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The link: https://vsco.co/chrysc/gallery

Is it possible to create a scraper goes to that link and clicks on each picture, writes the description into a single textfile?

So for example:

the textfile would look like:

```
Circle Loop #vsco #kusama
#vsco #kusama ✨
#vsco White has eyes?
etc...
```

I was thinking "BeaustufilSoup4" or "Selenium" could work? Would this be a difficult script and I should just do this process manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will print all descriptions to the screen and to the file:

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://vsco.co/chrysc/gallery'

html_data = requests.get(url).text

data = json.loads(re.search(r'window\.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = (\{.*\})', html_data).group(1))

# uncomment this to see all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print description to the screen:
for img in data['entities']['images'].values():
    print(img['description'])

# print description to the file:
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for img in data['entities']['images'].values():
        print(img['description'], file=f_out)
```

Prints:

```
Circle Loop #vsco #kusama
#vsco #kusama ✨
#vsco White has eyes?
missing nights like these #vsco
#vsco :)
#vsco
#vsco Water//Alberta
who she is, is a result of who she was 
#vsco #chrystene peace out
#vsco #chrystene DO NOT DISTURB
#vsco #chrystene Beautiful Morning
#vsco #chrystene Paradise
#vsco Wandering Fairy Cat ✨
#vsco close your eyes so you’re less embarrassed ???
```

And writes the same contents to the file named `output.txt`.

Comment: Damn!! You saved me a lot of time! Is it possible to factor in multiple pages? The gallery is a 'endless scrolling' kind-of website

Comment: @Aedam Well, the gallery is loaded through JavaScript, maybe using `selenium` will be useful here. You can find examples around here on SO.

Comment: @Aedam If you can simulate the Ajax requests using the `requests` module, then this is better way - `selenium` is more heavyweight compared to `requests`.

Comment: So for example, I would make a request to that first link, process it etc using your code, then get the next_cursor and add it to the end of the link and somehow make that a loop? until there's no more next_cursors/errors out? Is that correct?

Comment: @Aedam Yes, something like this. But every page is different (uses various cookies, headers, ...) You can use Firefox developer tools (Chrome has something similar too) to debug the requests/headers...

Comment: Thanks you! Really appreciate the help